# Keeping updated objects relations in React state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, relation

I am trying to figure it out, how should I properly create a JSON model for a React  component state. 
Since now I always used Entity Framework and virtual properties to connect related "tables", so now when I want to do similar thing in React and JSON I have don't really know how to proceed.

This is my simplified model:

```
{
  "myModel": {
    "Categories": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Cat1",
        "Active": true
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Cat2",
        "Active": false
      }
    ],
    "Components": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Component1",
        "CategoryId": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Component2",
        "CategoryId": 1
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Component3",
        "CategoryId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How to effectively join these two "tables"?
For example if I want to filter `Components`, whose `Category` is `Active`?

In my second approach I changed model to contain the whole Category object in Component:

```
..."Components": [
 {
   "Id": 1,
   "Name": "Component1",
   "Category": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Cat1",
        "Active": true
      }
 },...
```

This allowed me to use `filter(a=>a.Category.Active==true)` function very easily, but then the problem is when I make changes to a property of one of the `Categories`, the change does not reflect to `Components`.

What is the best approach in this situation? Is is better to update all `Component[].Category` on each `Category` change or loop through all Categories to find the correct one each time I need to filter or group Components on CategoryId?

I need to have `Categories` in separate array, because they are not always all in use by `Components`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily aggregate the data and filter for active Components by using your data structure:

```
  const activeComponents = myModel.Components.filter(component => {
    let isActive = false;
    const componentCategory = myModel.Categories.filter(
      category => category.Id === component.CategoryId
    );
    if (componentCategory.length && componentCategory[0].Active)
      isActive = true;
    return isActive;
  });
```

You can also shorten the code in case there is always a Category for each CategoryId:

```
  const activeComponents = myModel.Components.filter(
    component =>
      myModel.Categories.filter(
        category => category.Id === component.CategoryId
      )[0].Active
  );
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but because of the amount of the code I thought something may be wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state) docs for that. You should not duplicate data and keep it as flat as possible. So your second approach is not advisable, because it both duplicates and nests the data. The components should be inserted into an object where the keys are the ids. Additionally, you could keep all active components in an string array, which contains all active component ids and and retrieve them by iterating over the active component array and extracting the component with the id from the mapping object.

Comment: I quickly found out that data duplication is very bad idea. Since it is a "small" application, I do not consider using Redux yet.